# Count number of exactly matching words in a string

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr, stringi

I have a tibble with an `id` column and a column that capture some `text_entry` that people inputted.
**Goal**: Compare each person's `text_entry` to a `key` and count the number of *perfectly* typed words.
For example, if my inputs were:

```
df <- tribble(~id, ~text_entry,
              1, "It was a Saturday night in December.",
              2, " It was a Saturday night",
              3, "It wuz a Sturday nite in",
              4, "IT WAS A SATURDAY",
              5, "was a Saturday"); df

key <- "It was a Saturday night in December."
```

Then I would want the following:

```
df2 <- tribble(~id, ~text_entry, ~words_correct, 
               1, "It was a Saturday night in December.", 7, # whole string perfect
               2, " It was a Saturday night", 5,             # first 5 words perfect
               3, "It wuz a Sturday nite in", 3,             # misspelled "was", "Saturday" and "night"
               4, "IT WAS A SATURDAY", 0,                    # case-sensitive
               5, "was a Saturday", 3); df2                  # ok to start several words into the key
```

I'm completely striking out with `stringr`/`stringi` solutions. `tidyverse` always preferred, but I'm desperate for any solution.

Thanks so, SO much for your help & insights in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to split the string on whitespace and count the common words with `key`.

```
library(tidyverse)

keywords <- strsplit(key, '\\s+')[[1]]

df %>%
  mutate(text = str_split(text_entry, '\\s+'), 
         words_correct = map_dbl(text, ~sum(.x %in% keywords)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     id text_entry                             words_correct
#  <dbl> <chr>                                          <dbl>
#1     1 "It was a Saturday night in December."             7
#2     2 " It was a Saturday night"                         5
#3     3 "It wuz a Sturday nite in"                         3
#4     4 "IT WAS A SATURDAY"                                0
#5     5 "was a Saturday"                                   3
```

We can also do this in base R :

```
df$words_correct <- sapply(strsplit(df$text_entry, '\\s+'), 
                           function(x) sum(x %in% keywords))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract non-space parts and pass them to `str_detect()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(words_correct = map_dbl(str_extract_all(text_entry, "[^\\s]+"),
                                 ~ sum(str_detect(key, .))))

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      id text_entry                             words_correct
#   <dbl> <chr>                                          <dbl>
# 1     1 "It was a Saturday night in December."             7
# 2     2 " It was a Saturday night"                         5
# 3     3 "It wuz a Sturday nite in"                         3
# 4     4 "IT WAS A SATURDAY"                                0
# 5     5 "was a Saturday"                                   3
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thanks, @Darren Tsai!